# viewing 2 or more arrays in a listview in array adapter?

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-listview

im having a problem with this code:

```
public void calendarview()
{
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.calendarlist);

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "animobile", MODE_PRIVATE);

    int size = pref.getInt("clength", 0);
    String cdate[] = new String[size];
    String cevent[] = new String[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        cdate[i] = pref.getString("cdate" + i, null);
        cevent[i] = pref.getString("cdate" + i, null);
    }

    Log.w("athan","kalendaryo"+size);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cdate);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

}
```

with lv as listview like this:

```
private ListView lv;
```

now the problem is, i have this array `cdate` and `cevent` and i want them to be listed on an arrayadapter, but arrayadapter accepts only one arraylist.

i have also read lots of other related questions, but i only end up with same answer, "you have to make a custom adapter". but with this code, is it possible with custom adapter? the code is inside the:

```
public class calendarview extends Activity {
```

EDIT:
im still stuck, i created a class just like trevor-e said, this is the code:

```
class Event {
    private String cdate;
    private String cevent;
    public Event(String date, String event) {
        this.cdate = date; this.cevent = event;
    }

    public void setcdate(String cdate) {
        this.cdate = cdate;
    }
    public void setcevent(String cevent) {
        this.cevent = cevent;
    }
    public String cevent() {
        return cevent;
    }
    public String cdate() {
        return cdate;
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

and the ArrayAdapter is changed to:

```
ArrayAdapter<Event> arrayAdapter =      
    new ArrayAdapter<Event>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

now the code does not give any values. im a missing something?  it feels like i have to set the array into this class but i dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i cant understand this arrayadapter, i used table instead:

```
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.calendarlist);
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "animobile", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int size = pref.getInt("clength", 0);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView date = new TextView(this);
        date.setText(pref.getString("cdate" + i, null) + "    ");
        tr.addView(date);

        TextView event = new TextView(this);
        event.setText(pref.getString("cevent" + i, null));
        tr.addView(event);
        tl.addView(tr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an object to encapsulate one entry of each kind.  Something like this:

```
class Event {
    private String date;
    private String event;
    public Event(String date, String event) {
        this.date = date; this.event = event;
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

And then construct an ArrayList of those objects to use for your adapter.  So in this case it would be `ArrayAdapter<Event>`.

edit: As TenFour04 said in the comments it is also wise to override the toString() method for Event since by default the adapter will call toString() on each entry to get a representation to display.  Or you can choose to subclass the adapter to get finer control.

Comment: And if you don't want to subclass ArrayAdapter, you should also override toString() in this class and concatenate the date and event. ArrayAdapter by default just uses toString() to get the value it will use in the ListView.

Comment: @TenFour04 Thanks, very good point.  I mentioned that in my post now.

Comment: thank you for you reply, but it seems i lack the knowledge to fully understand your answers. can you please elaborate a little more? thank you for your understanding

Comment: @AthanSubion Right now you have an ArrayAdapter of type String.  If you create a new Object to store both the String entries you want to display, then you can instead use an ArrayAdapter of that type so you can pass through both at once.  If you do that, then you may have to override some methods in ArrayAdapter to handle that.

Comment: @AthanSubion Did you then create a list of Event objects out of cevent and cdate arrays that you have?  You should pass that into your adapter. And for the correct text to display, you may need to override the toString() method in Event.